# ngx-mat-datetime-picker changes format unexpected

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using ngx-mat-datetime-picker in the following way:

**HTML:**

```
<mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [ngxMatDatetimePicker]="picker"  placeholder="Choose a date & time" ng-readonly="true">
          
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="$any(picker)"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      
          <ngx-mat-datetime-picker #picker></ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
      </mat-form-field>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
export const MY_FORMAT = 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm';

const CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS: NgxMatDateFormats = {
    parse: {
      dateInput: MY_FORMAT,
    },
    display: {
      dateInput: MY_FORMAT,
      monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
      dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
      monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
    },
  };
```

and added this to **providers**:

```
{ provide: MY_FORMAT, useValue: CUSTOM_DATE_FORMATS }
```

This works when using the calendar icon to input the date and time.

It comes out like this.

[image: Format when using the calendar icon]

but when i manually change the seconds the format of the date and time changes.

And becomes this:

[image: format after changing the seconds from 25 to 24]

for some reason this also changes the month and date in the calendar